# Town infested with alien parasites causing people to lose their teeth

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, horror

I saw this movie a long time ago. The action takes places in a small town as far as I can remember. The people there get "infested" with some sort of parasite and they start losing their teeth. I only remember a particular scene where the lead character is in the bathroom in front of the mirror and he takes some pliers and pulls out a tooth so that the other people would not suspect he's not actually "infested". I think those "parasites" were of alien nature.

It probably appeared in late 80s or 90s.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Might be [**The Tommyknockers**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106156/) *(1993)*.

[image: Tommyknockers] <sup>[[Source]](http://serialkillercalendar.com/VHSWASTELAND/VHS-WASTELAND-AUGUST-2.html)</sup>

But instead of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tommyknockers_(TV_miniseries)) I'll quote [The 34th Dimension](http://www.34thdimension.com/articles/53-the-second-annual-valentines-day-horror-movie-marathon.html):

> It’s been a long time since I’ve seen *The Tommyknockers*, but from what I remember the plot goes like this: blah blah blah, midwestern American town, blah blah blah, alien things show up, blah blah, **A GUY PULLS OUT HIS OWN FUCKING TEETH.**
>
> If I gave you a better explanation than that I’d pretty much be copy/pasting the IMDB or Wikipedia entry. But, c’mon. **He pulls out his own goddamn teeth. With pliers.** And then shows them to his wife. C’moooooon. Did I mention it has aliens?

Comment: I love the quote from The 34th Dimension.

Answer (score 4):

Is it [Cabin Fever 2:Spring Fever](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabin_Fever_2%3a_Spring_Fever#section_1)

In Cabin fever 2 virus spread through drinking water and infected people looses their teeths. During one sex scene the lady looses her teeths and boy got shocked.

Comment: It's not Cabin Fever 2. The movie I'm talking about is much older.

Comment: You didn't mentioned how old in question.