# In the movie adaptation of George Orwell's 1984, how was the pulling out of Winston's tooth filmed?

Tags: film-techniques, 1984

In [1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four_(1984_film)), Winston Smith's tooth is pulled out by O'Brien while he is being tortured. Did they actually pull out the actor's tooth for the scene or was it a visual effect?

Comment: Related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9221/how-do-they-show-a-tooth-less-mouth

Comment: Thanks for the link. I suppose it isn't easy to find the info about this particular movie sot he general info is going to have to suffice :)

Comment: I can't find anything specific on the movie itself...but I've only done a cursory search.

Comment: I seriously doubt they'd yank the lead actor's tooth out on camera, for many reasons. Probably one of Nobby's options in Paulie's link, with a fake set of teeth as the safest bet (because they're supposed to be rotted out, and I doubt Hurt could do that to himself).

Comment: Yeah - no-one allows a tooth to be pulled in a scene.  The closest I've ever heard was Brad Pitt getting his tooth deliberately chipped (and later cosmetically restored) by a dentist for Fight Club.

Comment: Or less tooth related, Steve Carrell actually did get his chest waxed for the scene in The 40 Year Old Virgin. But chest hair isn't the same as pulling an (otherwise healthy) tooth.